# Get exit code from last pipe (stdin)

Tags: bash, exit-code

I would like to be able to create a bash function that can read the exit code of the command before the pipe. I'm not sure it is possible to have access to that.

- `echo "1" | grep 2` returns a 1 status code
- `echo "1" | grep 1` returns a 0 status code

Now I would like to add  a third command to read the status, with a pipe:

- `echo "1" | grep 2 | echo $?` will echo "0", even if the status code is 1.

I know I can use the `echo "1" | grep 2 && echo "0" || echo "1"`, but I would prefer to write it using a pipe.

Is they anyway to do that (it would be even better if it was working on most shells, like bash, sh, and zsh)

Comment: Why would you like to use a pipe for this? `echo "1" | grep 2;echo $?` would work fine.

Comment: Because I might also need what comes from stdin. However, I prefer your solution than the one from @mattinbits

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need the status from *within* the pipeline?

Comment: Like `tee` gets stdin and puts it into a file and passes it to the next command, I would just like to be able get the status and pass everything to the next command. So that I can do `echo "1" | debug | long | command | here` so that I can now debug the status of a pipe without having to write multiple lines (and so that is repeatable). Does that make sense ?

Comment: I'm mostly using my `debug` function when I run some commands in my bash, so I would prefer if I could do it in one line.

Comment: You can always access stdin via `/dev/stdin` or using `<0` anyway

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to get the exit status *before* the next stage of the pipeline. Something like

```
exec 3> debug.txt
{ echo "1"; echo "$?" >&3; } | long | command | here
```

You can't (easily) encapsulate this in a function, since it would require passing a properly quoted string and executing it via `eval`:

```
debug () {
    eval "$@"
    echo $? >&3
}

# It looks easy in this example, but it won't take long to find
# an example that breaks it.
debug echo 1 | long | command | here
```

You have to write the exit status to a different file descriptor, otherwise it will interfere with the output sent to the next command in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can do this with the `PIPESTATUS` variable

```
echo "1" | grep 1
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # returns 0
echo "1" | grep 2
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # returns 0
echo "1" | grep 2
echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]} # returns 1
```

Comment: The last command isn't inside a pipe. `$?` would work much better because I want to retrieve the last status code, not the nth

Comment: @edi9999 put it in the command then `echo "1" | grep 2 | echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}`

Comment: Yes but if I have three commands instead of two it wouldn't work : eg        `echo "1" | sed | grep 2 | echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]`

Comment: It should also be usable if they are pipes after the current pipe, like this : `echo "1" | sed | grep 2 | echo ${PIPESTATUS[1] | echo "3"`

Comment: $PIPESTATUS takes the result of the last command, not of the current one. To test it: `echo "1" \n echo "ls" | grep "ls" | echo ${PIPESTATUS[${#PIPESTATUS[@]}-2]}` returns  `-bash: PIPESTATUS: bad array subscript`